# Orbeon Forms Section Templates

Tags: orbeon

Is there a way to make it so that section templates are not read-only in form builder? The idea is to have a set of fields that users can quickly add to forms but still be able to add static read-only data, modify field names etc, if desired.

Comment: Sorry I missed your question in December.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good but currently this is not possible. I entered two separate issues to track the ideas:

- allow the user to modify control values [#2051](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2051)
- allow the user to modify the section template [#2052](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2052)

Neither is very easy to do, unfortunately.